# seaborn v0.12 new object API: how to get back the matplotlib Figure (or Axes) object?

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm trying out the new object API of seaborn. The API is introduced in version 0.12.
However, I have difficulty retrieving the underlying Matplotlib Axes/Figure object. For example, when using `sns.lineplot`, it returns a Matplotlib `Axes` object, and we can call the methods of the `Axes` afterwards, as in:

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
y = sns.lineplot(data=tips, x='size', y='tip') # y is an Axes object
y.set_title("my title")
y
```

Is there any way that I can retrieve the Matplotlib object from the new object API, as in:

```
x = (
    so.Plot(tips, "size", "tip")
    .add(so.Line(), so.Agg())
)
type(x) # seaborn._core.plot.Plot, not Matplotlib
```

Comment: Interesting question. One option might be to use [`Plot.on`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.objects.Plot.on.html#seaborn.objects.Plot.on), i.e. create the matplotlib figure or Axes yourself and then pass to seaborn. The docs note: "Using `Plot.on` also provides access to the underlying matplotlib objects, which may be useful for deep customization."

Comment: The conventional code is the same as the following code when written in object style. `(
    po.Plot(tips, "size", "tip")
    .add(so.Line(), so.Agg())
    .add(so.Band(), so.Est())
    .label(title='My Title')
)`

Comment: This could be of interest:
https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/objects_interface.html#integrating-with-matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

I get the `matplotlib` object as follows:

```
#assign the Plot object to a variable
p = (
      so.Plot...
    )               
matplotlib_handle = p.plot()._figure #returns the matplotlib figure
```

Or, in a single line:

```
matplotlib_handle = ( so.Plot... ).plot()._figure
```

This has worked for me. You can then get `matplotlib_handle.gca()`, `.axes`, etc. Not sure if there's a way of avoiding the call to `plot()`.

Some previous suggestions also provide a way of customising `so.Plot` using `matplotlib` (useful for getting `Plot` objects onto a `plt.subplots()` grid, amongst other things), but I don't think it's the same as directly accessing the `matplotlib` object.